# cannot serve file to browser for downloadingusing Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, download, playframework-1.x

I am trying to serve a csv file to the browser side using play framework 1.2.5.
Here is the code:

```
public static Result downloadData() throws Throwable {    
        .
        .
        .
        File file =new File(file_written_to);
        .
        response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FILENAME");
        return ok(file);
    }
```

However it keeps saying:

> The method ok() in the type Controller is not applicable for the arguments (File)

after I tried to test it with `return ok("hello")`, it still says:

> The method ok() in the type Controller is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Also for the response(), it says this method is undefined.

Anyone has any ideas about where the problem is with my code? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `File` in your import statement the same kind of `File` as `ok()` calls for? You may have imported the wrong type.

Comment: Add proper Play version as a tag and/or description

Comment: @MartinCarney I even tried ok("200"); and it gave me the error said string is not the right type..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are reading Play 2.x docs. Try:

```
renderBinary(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try play clean and then play compile run. Sometimes it breaks down...